# How can I show a popup window in my activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi guys I have an activity containing a google maps fragment in my app and I was wondering if is it possible to show a popup window when I push on any infoWindow with more information about that place. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom Dialog. Create a dialog that extends Dialog class. Then you override the methods that you need.In the method show() you can inflate your own layout and associate the actions that you need. This is a little example of the show() method:

```
    @Override
    public void show() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        setCancelable(false);

        super.setContentView(layout);

        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)).setText(title);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvContent)).setText(content);
        dialog = layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog);

        Button btCancelar = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btCancelar);


        super.show();

    }
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Yesterday I haven't time anymore but today I will try it :) thank u so much

Comment: is it compatible with android < 3.0 too ?

Comment: If I make a new class that extend Dialog I can't pass a context from show() .. how can I do with context??

Comment: I solved with this !! Thank you so much !! Just pass the context to the class that extend Dialog :D

Comment: Fantastic, you can pass the context in your own constructor when you create the customDialog. Then, you call show() method.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its possible to create window in map fragment. But still be clear about your question. Do you need popup window on click of some place in map or u need popup like alert message? Be specific!

Comment: Ok I only need a popup window, not an alert. I have my markers on the map. When I push on a marker a custom infoWindow with some details come out and now I want, when i push on the relative infoWindow, a bigger popup window come out to show, more details like the phone number, the email address and other details.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom infowindow to show location details on map marker by using custom layout, by using below code:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow,
                        null);

                TextView txt_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_title);
                txt_title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView txt_snippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_snippet);
                txt_snippet.setText(strSnippet);

                return v;

            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {    

                return null;

            }
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already did a custom info window, what I wanna do is to create a greater window that appears when I click on infowindow. But thank you anyway :)